# UL menu with space between LI elements - how can this work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m trying to make a menu, with space between the li elements.
So I´m facing that onmouseout problem.
When the user is on some of these spaces, the onmouseout is dispatched.

I found this menu:

http://motion-twin.com/

The link, "Our Games", does have a space between the menu and the submenu.
If I keep the mouse between the space of the "Our Games" link and its submenu, nothing happens.
How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: If you could show some code for this, maybe we could help you better. Where abouts is your javascript code on this page for this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to use padding or line-height vs margin. I would use something like this to get started: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: My menu is a vertical menu with submenu. I need a little space between the LI elements, so I´m using margin-bottom. It works, but, when the mouse is on some of these spaces, it dispatches the onmouseout event. I´d like that the onmouseout event just dispatch if the mouse is outside the whole structure of the menu and submenu.
If the mouse is over a space between LI elements or menu and submenu, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a transparent gif in the background of the menu wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You should use margin-left or margin-right on the li elements...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to solve this, but when I encounter this problem, I solve it in one of two ways, depending on the restrictions:

1) The event that closes the menu, change it to mouseout for the UL element instead of the LI element.

OR

2) When the LI mouseout event fires, put it on a timeout `tClosing = setTimeout('fncClose', 1000);`, and on the LI mousein event, just `clearTimeout(tClosing);`.  What this does is delay the closing for a second.  There are some UX benefits to this as well, the users sometimes prefer it because menus do not collapse as quickly; useful for multi-tier menus